# Function-like macro invocation syntax

Tags: c, macros

I found the code below in a very old question about linked lists ("https://stackoverfloquestions/522010/how-do-i-build-a-onetwothree-linked-list-with-a-minimum-number-of-assignment-opew.com/") and what left me confused wasn't the linked list part in itself but the way this macro was defined. As I'm not very familiar with C, I wonder if anyone can help me break down this #deifine statement and maybe show me alternative solutions for a similar result. Thanks in advance for your attention!

```
#define build_list(...) \
    _build_list((sizeof((int []){ __VA_ARGS__ }))/(sizeof(int)), \
    (int []){ __VA_ARGS__ })

struct node * _build_list(size_t count, int values[count])
{
    struct node * next = NULL;

    for(size_t i = count; i--; )
    {
        struct node * current = malloc(sizeof *current);

        *current = (struct node){ values[i], next };
        next = current;
    }

    return next;
}
```

Comment: Do you recognize a compound literal when you see one?  If not, that would probably explain most of your confusion.

Comment: It is a macro that takes a variable number of arguments.  A normal macro accepts a specific number of parameters and you use the individual parameters however you like.  So `#define build_list(a,b) _build_list( (sizeof((int []){ a,b })) / (sizeof(int)), (int []){ a,b })` takes two parameters and calls _build_list with a size of 2 and an array of 2 items.  In the variable number case `__VA_ARGS__` is whatever is passed to the macro - it might be two items or it might be any other number of items.

Comment: When you say "alternative solutions for a similar result" what are you asking for?  You can make a macro or a function and either might take a specific number of parameters or a variable number.